# How to make whole div clickable and put a dynamic url in Django template?

Tags: html, django, dynamic, django-templates

I am trying to display a post (like a tweet in twitter) and when I display it I want the whole div to be clickable.
So this works. Website is working the way I wanted with this code;

```
<div onclick='location.href="{% url 'post' post.id %}";' style="cursor: pointer;"> 
  <a href="#"> some other links </a> // it will take user to another page
  <img src= "" > //some image
  <p> some content </p>
  <a href="#"> some other links </a>
</div>
```

But it gives me some warnings in the terminal (VScode), each of the error is showing the same thing (div onclick line ) but strangely giving different errors. And I don't use javascript for this part of the code.

I tried different syntax like changing " " to ''. but it doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Also in the code, it shows the line with red color as below, if it helps to figure what the problem is.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct ignore the warnings and red-underlines by VScode. Red-underlines are there because by default the language mode is HTML therefore sometimes use of `''` and `""` shows error but it is fine as per `Django Templating Engine`

If for any reason `onclick='location.href="{% url 'post' post.id %}";'` does not work use this `onclick='location.href="post/{{post.id}}";'`

Comment: it was helpful, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome friend :)

Answer (score 0):

before your "div" tag, put an "a" tag and give it the url. You don't need to repeat the url manytimes.

EXAMPLE:

[image]